# Recaptcha v.3 en dos formularios en la misma página

Tags: javascript, laravel, recaptcha

Buenas estoy intentando poner el recaptcha v3 en dos formularios que se encuentran en la misma vista, pero entran en conflicto entre si.

```
<form action="{{ route('web.enviarContacto') }}" class="formContacto" autocomplete="off" method="POST" id="demo-form">
   @csrf
   ....
   ....
   <button type="submit" class="btn g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mmmmmmmmm" 
                data-callback='onSubmit' 
                data-action='submit'>Enviar</button>
</form>


<form action="{{ route('web.solicitud') }}" class="formContacto" autocomplete="off" method="POST" id="solicitud">
   @csrf
   ....
   ....
   <button type="submit" class="btn g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mmmmmmmmmm" 
                data-callback='onSubmit' 
                data-action='submit'>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**El script de google:**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

<script>
    function onSubmit(token) {
      document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
    }

    function onSubmit(token) {
      document.getElementById("solicitud").submit();
    }
</script>
```

**Controlador**

```
 public function enviarContacto(Request $request)
    {
        $response = Http::asForm()->post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [
            'secret' => 'mmmmmmmm',
            'response' => $request->input('g-recaptcha-response')
        ])->object();
      ......
      ......
     }

 public function solicitud(Request $request)
    {
       $response = Http::asForm()->post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [
         'secret' => 'mmmmmmmm',
         'response' => $request->input('g-recaptcha-response')
        ])->object();
      ......
      ......
      return dd($response);
         }
```

Siendo así, me lleva todo el rato a la respuesta del segundo formulario.

Comment: Cierto @Marcos . Es una tonteria pero publica solución en una respuesta, ya que a alguien le puede suceder. Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que a ambos formularios le estas pasando la misma función `onSubmit`, la cual estas pisando al definirla por segunda vez.

#### Solución:

Necesitas crear una nueva funcion, por ejemplo, `onSubmit2` para el `form#solicitud`

```
<form action="{{ route('web.solicitud') }}" class="formContacto" autocomplete="off" method="POST" id="solicitud">
   @csrf
   ....
   ....
   <button type="submit" class="btn g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mmmmmmmmmm" 
                data-callback='onSubmit2' 
                data-action='submit'>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

y en el `Javascript`

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

<script>
    function onSubmit(token) {
      document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
    }

    function onSubmit2(token) {
      document.getElementById("solicitud").submit();
    }
</script>
```